# Using multilingual and localeurl in django

Tags: python, django, django-multilingual

Using django-multilingual and localeurl.

Small sample of my main page view:

```
def main(request): #View for http://www.mysite.com/
    name = Dog.objects.all()[0].full_name #this is a translated field
    return render_to_response("home.html", {"name" : name})
```

Entering http://www.mysite.com/ redirects me to http://www.mysite.com/ru/ and "name" variable gets russian localization. For now it's ok...

But...

Entering http://www.mysite.com/en/ shows me same russian loclized variable.

During my experiments with debuger I've discovered:

- request.LANGUAGE_CODE is changing properly according to /en/ or /ru/ url suffix (thanx to localeurl)
- invoking multilingual.languages.set_default_language() makes "name" variable change loclization

The question is: should I change language of django-multilingual to request.LANGUAGE_CODE in each of my view myself, or it must be solved automaticly and I've done something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem, after rotation with positions in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES I've got the right order:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'localeurl.middleware.LocaleURLMiddleware',
    'multilingual.middleware.DefaultLanguageMiddleware',
    'multilingual.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
)
```

I comment #'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware' its doing the same as 'localeurl.middleware.LocaleURLMiddleware' I think.

Answer (score 1):

after removing django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware it worked for me also ...